# Publish message to DLX along with error codes with Spring AMQP

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am able to publish messages to DLX when they are not able to process due to insufficient information or any other issues with the message received by binding DLX for the queue through Spring AMPQ.

For instance, invoice received with missing of billable hours and/or no employee id present it it.

```
{
  "invoiceId": "INV1234",
  "hourRate": 18.5,
  "hoursWorked": 0,
  "employeeId": "EMP9900"
}
```

Due to less size of request body, it's easy to understand what is the issue. But, we have some considerable request body length and 15-20 validation points.

Producer of the message expecting what is the issue when pushing back the message to publishing back them through DLX.

I have the following two thoughts to address this requirements.

***Option #1: Append the errors information to the original message.***

```
{
  "message": {
    "invoiceId": "INV1234",
    "hourRate": 18.5,
    "hoursWorked": 0,
    "employeeId": "EMP9900"
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "errorCode": "001",
      "errorMessage": "Invalid no. of hours."
    },
    {
      "errorCode": "002",
      "errorMessage": "Employee not found in the system."
    }
  ]
}
```

***Option #2 : Add additional errors object in the headers***

Out of these two options,

1. what is the better way of handling this requirements? And
2. Is there any in-built solution available in either spring-amqp or any other library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#async-listeners). The framework implements your #2 solution.

> Starting with version 1.3, a new `RepublishMessageRecoverer` is provided, to allow publishing of failed messages after retries are exhausted.

> ...

> The `RepublishMessageRecoverer` publishes the message with additional information in message headers, such as the exception message, stack trace, original exchange, and routing key. Additional headers can be added by creating a subclass and overriding additionalHeaders().

Comment: This worked perfect. Just turned off the exception trace by explicitly setting `message.getMessageProperties().setHeader("x-exception-stacktrace", null);`, since the message publishing through DLX will be pushed to respective tenants DL Queue through shovel plugin and giving exception trace to tenants may cause n/w traffic and also security issues. Please suggest, if there is another possibility to turn off giving exception trace.

Comment: `message.getMessageProperties().getHeaders().remove("x-exception-stacktrace");`